# Formula for the Involute of a Parameterized Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

For a grade 12 math assignment I've chosen to look at the involutes of parameterized curves and I'm afraid I've bitten off more than I can chew. I've found the formula on Wikipedia but even after I've searched around and experimented a little I can't seem to make sense of it. The formula I found (taken from Wikipedia) is:

$$
\vec{X}=\vec{C}_{a}(t)=\vec{c}(t)-\frac{\vec{c}^{\prime}(t)}{\left|\vec{c}^{\prime}(t)\right|} \int_{a}^{t}\left|\vec{c}^{\prime}(w)\right| d w
$$

I would appreciate it greatly if someone could spell out what the $w$ represents in this equation.

Thanks for any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$w$ just stands for the integration variable (it is a "dummy" variable, you can call it anything you want without changing the meaning). Your equation, in words, says:
"At any given point $c(t)$ on the curve, move along the tangent (unit direction vector $c'(t)/|c'(t)|$) an amount equal to the length of the curve measured from the point corresponding to $t=a$ (the value of the integral). In this way you get the point on the involute corresponding to $t$, $X(t)$".